# Create editor with multiple parts in Eclipse 4.x

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to create an application that can open files. When opening a file, an editor should open like in the normal Eclipse IDE. but i want in this Editor multiple Parts (e.g. TreeView of the opened data and data in plaintext)

Is there a way to describe the contents of this editor in the Application.e4xmi and then just opening this "view"?
like this:

```
Application.e4xmi:

 PartStack (id = "editor.partstack")
   |- Part (DataTreeViewer.java)
   |- Part (PlaintextViewer.java)
   \- Part (ImagePart.java)

OpenHandler.java:

 PartStack ps = openPartStack("editor.partstack");
 addToMainPartstack(ps);
```

Or do i have to describe the editor contents programmatically in the OpenHandler? like this:

```
OpenHandler.java:

 PartStack ps = createNewPartStack();
 ps.add(new DataTreeViewer());
 ps.add(new PlainTextViewer());
 ps.add(new ImagePart());
 addToMainPartstack(ps);
```

Comment: if you create a plug-in project with Eclipse, one of the templates is plug-in with a multi-page editor.

Answer (score 0):

I just used a `PartDescriptor` for the editor part and an ordinary `CTabFolder` for the pages in the editor.